# unable to display SVG file containing utf-8 charactersI

Tags: utf-8

I like to edit SVG drawings directly in Emacs. It is very convenient to toggle display of source versus drawing with the sequence Ctrl-C ctrl-C. But, when the file contains text in utf-8, Emacs cannot display the drawing, unless the file has just been read or saved. Everytime I modify the buffer, I must save it if I want to display the drawing. Is this a bug or is there some setting to solve it?

Comment: Certainly sounds like a bug, so I would `M-x report-emacs-bug` -- and please include an example when you do (and here, if this question remains open), so that people have something to test.

Comment: Bug sent using M-x report-emacs-bug. Her is the example sent along:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="100mm" height="100mm" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path transform="matrix(20,0,0,20,50,40)" stroke-width="0.1" fill="none"
     stroke="magenta" d="M0,1c0.5519,0 1,-0.4481 1,-1M1,0c0,-0.5519 -0.4481,-1 -1,-1M0,-1 c-0.5519,0 -1,0.4481 -1,1M-1,0c0,0.5519 0.4481,1 1,1"/>
    <text text-anchor="middle" font-size="7" stroke="none" fill="black"
   x="50" y="88">Four cubic Bézier curves</text>
</svg>